# Want another way shortcode about sqlcode

Tags: mysql, sql, shortcode, short

please, i want find another way

**example data**

| date | tomato | phone | book | pen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-15 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2022-05-15 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 |

**i see this result**

| date | tomato | phone | book | pen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-15 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 3 |

**i use this**

```
insert into sales.copy 
select date, 
       sum(tomato), 
       sum(phone), 
       sum(book), 
       sum(pen) 
from copy 
where date = '2022-05-15';

delete from sales.copy 
where date = '2022-05-15' 
LIMIT 2;
```

**but i want another way this part short**

```
'date, sum(tomato), sum(phone)...'
```

Comment: There is no short way...and you are missing `group by` clause

Comment: I'd expect an error for your select. (Add a GROUP BY.)

Comment: LIMIT but no ORDER BY?

Comment: @jarlh `LIMIT but no ORDER BY` it will make sense if only one value match the criteria

Comment: @ErgestBasha, even less sense, since LIMIT isn't needed then.

Comment: You want to roll up existing creating a new row then delete the existing rows?  Does sales.copy have  a way of uniquely identifying rows ? please publish table definition.

Comment: Thanks everybody, we not found another way, but that answer is help, will my develop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just group the result

```
select date, 
       sum(tomato), 
       sum(phone),
       sum(book), 
       sum(pen) 
from copy 
where date = '2022-05-15' 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstood  the question ... `but I want another way this part short` 'date, sum(tomato), sum(phone)...'